# Searching a sliding window protocol implementation for tcp for linux kernel

Tags: c, networking, network-protocols

I want to analyze the sliding window protocol which TCP uses. I am not able to find the source code for the same. Can anyone tell me where can I get this? Which protocol does it use ? Go back n or selective repeat?

Comment: It's described in the RFC. No need for source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tcp_*.c` files in the [`net/ipv4`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree;f=net/ipv4;h=d408b655f1461ccca682fc993d56437e86fd6fbe;hb=HEAD) directory of the kernel source.

For example [`tcp_vegas.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=net/ipv4/tcp_vegas.c;h=80fa2bfd7edef91e309119d2b5bda953342e1e1b;hb=HEAD) implements [*TCP Vegas: End to end congestion avoidance on a global internet.*](http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/eecs/summer2010/cs372/papers/tcp/TCPVegas.pdf)

Have a look at [CUBIC TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUBIC_TCP). It is implemented in [`tcp_cubic.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=net/ipv4/tcp_cubic.c;h=a9077f441cb27b693d8ad1d710e4dba67aa93ebb;hb=HEAD), though I'm not sure if the statement that it is still the default is correct (that information is in the article since December 2007).

Comment: I am not able to find the sliding window protocol implementation for TCP in net/ipv4.